# What are the differences in functionality as far as Dashboarding goes between SharePoint 2010 standard and SharePoint 2010 Enterprise?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

Specifically, what sort of dashboarding CAN I do on a standard license? I have to convince my boss we need to upgrade to an enterprise license. Thanks!

Comment: what you mean about dashboarding? there are many dashboard i.e Developer Dashboard for troubleshooting, BI Dashboard..so please tell us which one you looking for?

Comment: I'm not sure. My boss likes the idea of being able to show a variety of data in a visual format that updates dynamically. The exact format has not been set in stone. The only information that I have is that they would like some sort of visual representation of data in a list or in a Excel worksheet and they would like that visualization to update dynamically as the data changes. They just want to know what IS possible with the current setup (standard license) in order to determine if we should take advantage of the Dashboard Designer with Enterprise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

again its depend, what type of data and source of data...
if you have excel workbooks and you want visual representation then you need Excel Calculation service...which required Enterprise License.

PerformancePoint Services in Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 is a performance management service that you can use to monitor and analyze your business. By providing flexible, easy-to-use tools for building dashboards, scorecards, reports, and key performance indicators (KPIs), PerformancePoint Services can help everyone across an organization make informed business decisions that align with companywide objectives and strategy....you need Enterprise license....

All BI features required Enterprise i.e powepivot, performance point, ECS, Visio services, Reporting services etc.

In nutshell you need Enterprise edition.

Answer (score 0):

PerformancePoint Services are not included in standard edition. So you can't create dashboards in PerformancePoint Dashboard Designer. You can still use third party solutions or develop your own web-parts that act like dashboards. That might be more cost-effective than paying addition price for the Enterprise license. On the other hand, Enterprise edition includes a ton of useful insights features like Visio services, PowerPivot, Excel Services, Business Intelligence center etc.

Comment: Does this mean there is no dashboarding capability in the standard license? Or is it just limited functionality?

Comment: Simple answer is - no. AFAIK, there are no out-of-the-box dashboards that update dynamically in SharePoint 2010 standard.

Answer (score 0):

The only real options outside of the Enterprise licence are XSLT and JavaScript - or more likely jQuery.  These will allow you to create visualisations of list and library data but do not really offer any end-user level customisation.

Some examples of what is possible with XSLT are http://paylord.wordpress.com/2012/03/18/sharepoint-list-risk-matrix-using-xslt/ and http://paylord.wordpress.com/2012/05/05/xslt-dashboard/ - both of these and similar are possible with the standard licence.

A couple of charting plugins are http://www.jqplot.com/ and http://www.amcharts.com/ - these offer more flexibility in presentation but also require more implementation.  Again these options are available using a standard licence.

So it is possible to create dashboards without but the enterprise licences will certainly provide you with more flexibility.  In particular I am a big fan of Excel services - http://paylord.wordpress.com/2013/04/20/excel-rest-meets-xsl/